# Passing an attribute to Doctrine AbstractIdGenerator

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I need to pass LoggerInterface to the **MyGenerator** used in **@ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class=MyGenerator::class)**

Doctrine does not use the symfony container to instantiate the generator and I'm ending up with an Exception **Too few arguments to function** How can I use the LoggerInterface in my id generator ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to inject LoggerInterface into MyGenerator class, as it's not a service and has nothing to do with the service container. However, in AbstractIdGenerator there is an EntityManager available, which provides a foundation for a workaround solution in order to propagate logs via a database table. After that, you'll be able to fetch log messages from a table via cronjob and write proper logs or do whatever you need.

```
class MyGenerator extends AbstractIdGenerator
{
    public function generate(EntityManager $em, $entity)
    {
        $identifier = '...'; // generate an identifier

        // push a log message to a db
        $query = $em->createQuery('INSERT INTO db.logger (id, message, created_at) VALUES (null, :message, NOW())');
        $query->setParameter('message', 'Log message...');
        $query->execute();

        return $identifier;
    }
}
```